# Activeadmin-ajax_filter gem doesn't display the results in a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rubygems, activeadmin

Using `activeadmin-ajax_filter` gem with ActiveAdmin gives me a strange result after I select a value in a previous drop-down. The dropdown is empty, it only shows the appropriate values after I start typing the name of a result. For example, in one dropdown I select a `color`, and in the second dropdown should be the colors, but they are not displayed When I click the second drop-down, I can only type, but I can't select the values, cause they are not present. Here is the code I have in a partial:

```
<% f.input :option %>
<% f.input :option_value, as: :ajax_select, data: {
    url: filter_admin_option_values_path,
    search_fields: [:value],
    static_ransack: { active_eq: true },
    ajax_search_fields: [:option_id] } %>
```

And in `OptionValue` resource I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register OptionValue do
  include ActiveAdmin::AjaxFilter
  #.....
end
```

How can I "pre-populate" the second dropdown with values after selecting the value in the first dropdown?